# how i can move from input to input with enter not tab

Tags: javascript

i mean i want make the 'enter' key go from the current input to the next
i mean the 'tab' key function
how i can make 'enter' key do the 'tab' key function
in javascipt

Comment: Please don't do that. It will make me hate you if I ever have to use that form.

Comment: i will not do but just i want know how

Comment: You are breaking a well established UI/UX principle. It just like making your right mouse button behave like the left one. and the left like the right.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with both of the comments. The worst thing you can do for a user friendly form is breaking the way forms usually work. Altough, if you really want to do it, you have to use a hander on each input for the enter key (key id is 13) and then focuses the next input using the focus() function. That post might help you: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1140915

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":input).keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.keyCode === 10) // 10 is for mac
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).next(":input").focus();
        }
    })
});
```

This may work if all of your input types are at the same level (siblings).
Otherwise you may need to cache off the $(":input) array and loop through that manually.

Comment: Using current Safari and Chrome on a Mac, `event.keyCode === 13` works fine.